# Wildly ramified extension field

Tags: nt.number-theory, non-archimedean-fields, ramification, field-extensions

Given an algebraically closed complete valued field $(k,|.|)$ with characteristic 0, such that the residue field $\tilde{k}$ has a positive characteristic, and consider the complete extension  $(\Omega,|.|)$ of $k$ defined as follows, $\Omega$ is the completion of $k(T)$ with respect to the Gauss norm (the Gauss norm is defined over $k[T]$ by $\sum_{i=0}^n a_i T^i\mapsto \max_i|a_i|$ extends to $k(T)$).

Let $(\Omega',|.|)$ be a finite extension of $(\Omega,|.|)$. In the case where $\tilde{\Omega'}$ is purely inseparable over $\tilde{\Omega}$ and given an element $\alpha\in \Omega'$ such that $\Omega'=\Omega(\alpha)$, is there any way to compute
$$|\sigma(\alpha)-\alpha|$$
where $\sigma\in Gal(\Omega^{alg},\Omega)$ ($\Omega^{alg}$ is the algebraic closure of $\Omega$) and $\sigma(\alpha)-\alpha\ne 0$?